# Why I see an error when I use "unit of work" with generic interface?

Tags: c#

I have a generic class repository named: `GenericRepository` and also I have a generic Interface named: `IGenericRepository` and `Product` is one of my tables in the database.

When I'm using "Unit Of Work" with this generic repositories in this way:

```
public class UnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
    GroceryStore_DBEntities db = new GroceryStore_DBEntities();
    private IGenericRepository<Product> _genericRepository;
    public IGenericRepository<Product> GenericRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_genericRepository == null)
            {
                _genericRepository = new  GenericRepository<Product>(db);
            }
            return _genericRepository;
        }
    }}
```

I face 2 errors that you can see below :

1. > Error  CS0311  The type 'GroceryStore.DataLayer.Context.Product' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'GenericRepository<TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'GroceryStore.DataLayer.Context.Product' to 'GroceryStore.DataLayer.Repositories.IGenericRepository<GroceryStore.DataLayer.Context.Product>'.
2. > Cannot implicitly convert type 'GroceryStore.DataLayer.Services.GenericRepository<GroceryStore.DataLayer.Context.Product>' to 'GroceryStore.DataLayer.Repositories.IGenericRepository<GroceryStore.DataLayer.Context.Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can you tell me where I went wrong? and Why? and How can I fix this?

---

I have these declarations:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity: class
{ }

public class GenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity: class, IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{ }
```

Comment: The problem would *appear* to be in how `GenericRespository` is defined. Which we cannot see.

Comment: Please show the constraint of the class and interface

Comment: Looks like your `IGenericRepository` class has a weird constraint on it, possibly `where TEntity : IGenericRepository<TEntity>`.

Comment: public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>where TEntity: class
                                    
                                               public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class,IGenericRepository<TEntity>

Comment: that is my constraint. sorry for the mess

Comment: Remove the second part of that constraint - it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class,IGenericRepository<TEntity> ` should be `GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class`

Comment: Yeah, that constraint is suspicious. Do you really mean to say that an entity must be a class that is a repository of entities?

Comment: Think he just place the interface on the wrong position

Comment: In which?   interface or class?   And also which part?

Comment: Normally you would make this sort of constraint if you were, for instance, saying you want a type that has an ordering operation: `SortableList<T> where T : IComparable<T>`   A sortable list is a list of T where every T can be compared for size to another T.

Comment: Are you intending the constraint to be an implemented interface of the class?  You have the constraints and the bases in the wrong order.  Bases come first!

Comment: I didn't understand what you said

Comment: **edit** your question to add more details. Especially when it's code. Code's unreadable in the comments, whereas you can paste code into the question and use the `{}` tool to show it *as* code.

Comment: I think it is quite clear that he used the wrong order. `GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class,IGenericRepository<TEntity>` should be `GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class`. From the code snippet you can see that `GenericRepository<>` is supposed to be an implementation of `IGenericRepository<>`

Comment: thanks but why it's wrong?

Comment: Because you say that `TEntity` must be a repository, instead of saying the class must be a repository (`IGenericRepository<TEntity>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity: class 
{ } 
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> 
  where TEntity:class, IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{ }
```

That means that the `TEntity` in a `GenericRepository<TEntity>` must be a respository of entities.

This sort of constraint is legal, but it is typically used for something like

```
class SortedList<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

That is, a sorted list of T requires that T be comparable to other Ts.

I think what you intended was

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> :
  IGenericRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity:class
{ }
```

Right? **The list of base classes and interfaces comes before the constraints; you put it in the constraints.**

That is, a class declaration goes like this:

```
class ClassName<T> : 
  BaseClass, 
  IInterface1, 
  IInterface2 
  where 
  T : CONSTRAINT,
      CONSTRAINT,
      ...
```

And the constraints have to come in the correct order as well. **Read the C# specification if you have questions about the syntax of a class declaration**.  You seem to have some confusion as to the order in which things happen.

Comment: thanks.It worked.But Can you tell me the reason that why my code is wrong?

Comment: @MohammadYoosefiyan: I'll add some notes. But you really should read the C# specification. It describes in detail the parts of a class declaration and the order in which they must appear.

Comment: thank you "Eric" very much.As you say , I didn't know the syntax with constraints.

Comment: And also,I have another question: What do you mean by "BaseClass"?

Comment: @MohammadYoosefiyan: If you do not understand the basics of OO programming you should not be messing around with advanced topics in generic types! Understand the basics before you attempt to do advanced work.

Comment: @MohammadYoosefiyan: What comes after `:` (just after the class name) is what the class derives from or implements. What comes after `where` are constraints for the generic type parameter. You want your repository class to **implement** `IGenericRepository<TEntity>` and your **type parameter** `TEntity` to be a class.

Comment: Exactly I want to say that.

Comment: See: [Object-Oriented Programming (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming) / [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming#Inheritance).